# Render view and scroll to top in BackboneJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

When I render a view in BackboneJS I just replace html of my container: `$('#container').html(this.template())` and it works fine, but when user scrolled page down a little and presses the button that renders other view, his 'scroll position' remains and the same place, which produces bad UX.

What I want to achieve is: when new backbone view is rendered the user should see the very top of the page (as what happens if you click ordinary link, which take you to another page with full page reload).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few ways to do this, here is some basic example to get you started.

In the click listener of your button, you could add a window.scrollTo(0,0) or $(window).scrollTop(0); to scroll to the top of the page.

Or your could place this scroll triggering method directly in your view render callback :

```
render: function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
    return this;
}
```

Or if your view is actually triggering a new route, you could also listen for that change of url and then trigger a scroll.

```
var router = new AppRouter();
router.on("route", function () {
    $("html,body").scrollTop(0);
});
```